# I listed my key prop, but still getting the following error: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from a rest API and then render it as text on my browser. However, I keep getting the following error:

> index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I have my key prop listed below.  Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?  I listed my key prop below thinking it would work this way in the render (I used this for another API call in a different project and it worked).

This is how the joke is set up in the API:

```
{
  "id": "R7UfaahVfFd",
  "joke": "My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad I had to take his bike away.",
  "status": 200
}
```

Here is my code for fetching it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class JokesApi extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            jokes: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'appliction/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState(prev => ({jokes: prev.jokes.concat(data.joke)})))
    }

    render () {
      var jokes;
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.jokes.map(joke => 
                  <div key={joke.id}>
                     <p>{jokes}</p>
                  </div>    
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


export default JokesApi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the array to the string representing the joke itself on fetch (`data.joke`) rather than the object itself (`data`), so `joke.id` ends up being undefined.

rather than getting `this.state.jokes` that looks like this:

```js
[{
  "id": "R7UfaahVfFd",
  "joke": "My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad I had to take his bike away.",
  "status": 200
}]
```

you are getting `data` that looks like this:

```js
["My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad I had to take his bike away."]
```

Here is the working code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class JokesApi extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            jokes: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState(prev => ({jokes: prev.jokes.concat(data)})))
    }

    render () {
      console.log(this.state.jokes);
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.jokes.map(joke => 
                  <div key={joke.id}>
                     <p>{joke.joke}</p>
                  </div>    
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default JokesApi;
```